# Issues to store hashtable values in session

Tags: asp.net

Why `session["anish"]` holds all *three* values of `hashTable` while it should store only *Two* values

```
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.Add("name", "anish");
    ht.Add("agge", "20");
    Session["anish"] = ht;
    ht.Add("sex", "male");
    Session.Add("manish", ht);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Hashtable are stored on the Heap in the memory and the hash tables are reference type. Hence when you say ht.add it will add in hashtable whoever refering to it.
So the Manish and anish both will have 3 values as they both refer to the same object ht.